# Unpermitted parameter in nested attributes using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to add multiple images using paperclip via nested attributes in rails 5.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but getting the following error referencing the attributes:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :image
```

I'm referencing the image attribute in my News Controller attributes, see below. The image doesn't save to the database.

**Models**

```
class News < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true
end

class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :news

has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :show => "600x600>" }, size: { less_than: 2.megabytes }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"]
end
```

**Controller**

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @news = News.new
    @news.images.build
  end

  def create
    @news = News.new(news_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @news.save
        format.html { redirect_to @news, notice: 'News was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @news }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @news.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  private
    def set_news
      @news = News.find(params[:id])
    end

    def news_params
      params.require(:news).permit(:title, :description, :category, images_attributes: [:id, :image, :news_id, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form.fields_for :image do |img| %>
   <%= img.file_field :image, multiple: true %>
<% end%>
```

**Sent results**

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kFPv2dZE6J9uHi4pu1qM+ZgDwXbFadjD2KjlhmLmk7LosumgB0vWQWA6zPJRe0b38JSSUZHYKRd4G6XAYEgmwA==", "news"=>{"title"=>"News Title", "description"=>"Random text goes in here.", "category"=>"", "image"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007feed58a5ba8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/n1/dt5dwx0n7rx59_3bpvp64x400000gp/T/RackMultipart20170822-995-firof5.jpg>, @original_filename="03.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"news[image][image]\"; filename=\"03.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}, "commit"=>"Update News", "id"=>"1-news-title"}
```

Comment: show the request sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unpermitted parameter: :image

Since you have `has_many :images`, you should have `form.fields_for :images` not `form.fields_for :image`

```
<%= form.fields_for :images do |img| %>
  <%= img.file_field :image, multiple: true %>
<% end%>
```

**Update:**

In that case you need to explicitly pass a `record_object` to the `fields_for`

```
<%= form.fields_for :images, @news.images.build do |img| %>
  <%= img.file_field :image, multiple: true %>
<% end%>
```

Also in order to send multiple values for image, it should be an array in the permitted params. You should change the `news_params` to below

```
def news_params
  params.require(:news).permit(:title, :description, :category, images_attributes: [:id, :news_id, :_destroy, image: []])
end
```

Comment: Thanks @pavan. When I try this method the file field disappears in the view and I'm unable to upload a file.

Comment: Appreciate your effort Pavan.

Comment: @pavan
I have the same problem.
I did as above and now shows me:
No handlers found for ...

Ps: I already have multipart in form.

Answer (score 0):

From your form, I could see that you're not sending the params in proper format to the controller.

Your params should contain `images_attributes` instead of `image`.

Change

```
<%= form.fields_for :image do |img| %>
   <%= img.file_field :image, multiple: true %>
<% end%>
```

to

```
<%= form.fields_for :images_attributes do |img| %>
   <%= img.file_field :image, multiple: true %>
<% end%>
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong. The problem is with name given to `fields_for`. It should be `imges` not `image`. The `images_attributes` is an attribute writer that gets created with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html